# A ideal data type for long utf8 strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, nvarchar, types

Is it true that `VARCHAR` type in mysql only suppory 255 characters data length?
if it is true what kind of datatype for UTF8 strings is useful for long texts? I'm using `utf8_persian_ci` datatype.

Note that TEXT datatype have problem with `utf8_persian_ci`.

Comment: List of mysql datatypes: http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max length of a `VARCHAR` in all current versions of MySQL is 65535.

In old releases of MySQL, `VARCHAR` had a max length of 255, but that's ancient history (where ancient is prior to March 2005).

The `CHAR` data type still has a limit of 255 characters.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true that VARCHAR type in mysql only suppory 255 characters data length?

[Not since MySQL 5.0.3, according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to store large amounts of text, I go for a TEXT field with the utf8_general_ci collation. To be honest, I am not sure what the difference between the different uft8 encodings are, but if you need to store longer texts, go for one of the TEXT types.

Answer (score 0):

you may use "utf8_general_ci collation"
I think this will help you, but m not sure

Comment: this is more like a comment. not an answer